# How can I use flexbox to create a horizontal scrolling image gallery where the image size is responsive up to a point

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a codepen showing where I've got to so far
https://codepen.io/HightonRidley/pen/MWbWYgw

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    justify-content: left; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
}

.flex-item {
    background: grey;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 350px;
    min-width:220px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: calc(2px + 0.25vw);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:calc(10px + 0.25vw);
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.myDiv {
    height:30px;
}
img {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div style="width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">some text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">some more text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/KGW0dPQ/500x500px-test-image.jpg" alt="500x500px-test-image"><div class="myDiv">lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The height of the area for the text underneath each image isn't really an issue as I think I've covered that ok.

Ideally the images will be responsive between a maximum and a minimum size, with an indeterminate number of images depending on usage. The number of images on display intially should be determined by the width of the containing div.
I don't want to use media queries.

I would appreciate any help - thanks in advance :)

Comment: max-width, max-height for images?

Comment: The image hosting service I'm using has gone down today. Typical! Hopefully it'll be ok again later today

Comment: Images ok again now :)

Comment: No, the flexbox item stays the same size.

Comment: @Temai Afif: No, the flexbox item stays the same size.